# How to create a 1080p video with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, resolution, 1080p

I'm using this command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i input.png -i audio.m4a -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv
```

I'm trying to make my videos 1080p how can I do that with the parameter I'm using? Where in that parameter should i add 1080 for 1080p quality?

Comment: The video will have the resolution of your image. Make sure it is 1080p.

Comment: Just add `-s hd1080` before output. Your image will need to have the same aspect ratio, or it will distort.

Comment: will it change quality?

Comment: will the video sound the same as audio file without transcoding after i add -s hd1080?

Comment: I meant is the quality of output will sound the same with or without -s hd1080?

Comment: The `-s` flag only affects the video resolution. It has no affect on audio. If you want the audio to remain unchanged you use the `-c:a copy` option, which is already part of your code. Yes. Audio will sound the same.

Comment: I did what you just told me to do but its kinda weird because i think resolution/quality depends on images. people use imagemagick but i dont have any idea how to use it.

Comment: 1080p will only affect quality if it is a recording option. Rescaling to 1080p (1920x1080 pixels) will only expose any flaws, particularly if the original video, or image is much smaller. As Gyan said, you need to input an image of the desired size to ensure the maximum quality is retained. You cannot add quality by converting to full HD with ffmpeg.

Comment: Can you teach me how to get full hd backgrounds or wallpaper with ffmpeg command? or imagemagick? I want to create my own image. what does imagemagick do anyways?